# Laravel Filter child row in hasOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this somewhere in my Laravel app

```
function result()
{
    return $this->hasOne(InvestigationResult::class, 'assignment_id', 'id');
}
```

If the instance is rejected, another report is made and the result of the model should be the last instance of `InvestigationResult` but laravel takes the first instance.

How do I specify condition on a relationship. If it is possible,  I would like to make complex queries to filter rows eligible for the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any of the usual Eloquent database functions to a relationship.

For example, if you want to return a row only if `rejected` is `false`:

```
return $this->hasOne(InvestigationResult::class, 'assignment_id', 'id')
    ->whereRejected(false);
```